# Apache subdomain configuration not working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I have a Debian 6 server that was configured by somebody else. I was asked to add a subdomain on that server.

I configured the DNS correctly (checked with `nslookup`), created the directory in `/var/www/` and then added new virtual host to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (in fact I copied one of the existing subdomain's file, and edited it):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysub.example.com"
    ServerName mysub.example.com
    ServerAlias www.mysub.example.com

    ErrorLog ...[path to file]
    CustomLog [path to file]

    RewriteEngine On 
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysub.example.com$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysub.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www/mysub.example.com>
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I added my host using `a2ensite` and restarted Apache but domain `mysub.example.com` is redirecting to `beta.example.com` which is our beta production site. What is weird, there is no configuration for `beta.example.com` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

What else should I do to enable this subdomain? I'm pretty sure that the configuration for `example.com` host is not blocking anything, because we have also a `blog.example.com` virtual host configured in that way and it is working perfectly.

**EDIT**

Some debug outputs:

```
root@xxx:~# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-example.com:18)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost blog.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/02-blog.example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost [here comes other unrelated domain name]
         port 80 namevhost forum.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/04-forum.example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/05-sth.example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost mysub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/06-mysub.example.com:1)
Syntax OK


root@xxx:~# grep -r 'mysub\.example\.com' /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:Alias /mysub /var/www/mysub.example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysub.example.com"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        ServerName mysub.example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        ServerAlias www.mysub.example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mysub.example.com-error_log"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/mysub.example.com-access_log" common
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysub.example.com$ [NC]
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysub.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
/etc/apache2/sites-available/06-mysub.example.com:        <Directory /var/www/mysub.example.com>

root@xxx:~# grep -r 'beta\.example\.com' /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ServerName beta.example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ServerAlias www.beta.example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-error_log"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-access_log" common
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ServerName beta.example.com:443
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ServerAlias www.beta.example.com:443
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-error_log"
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-example.com:        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-access_log" common
```

**EDIT 2**
I made a quick test. I disabled first virtual host (`beta.example.com`) with:

```
a2dissite 01-example.com
```

And then tried to access `mysub.example.com` and I was now redirected to `blog.example.com` - which is second one in order of sites enabled. So it looks like `mysub.example.com` is not being found and it falls into first bin of `*.example.com` subdomains it finds.

**EDIT 2**

Another test: I changed order of my configuration files so that my new subdomain would be the first (default) one. Right now:

```
root@xxx:~# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-example.com:14)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server mysub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-mysub.example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost mysub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-mysub.example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost beta.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/01-example.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost blog.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/02-blog.example.com:1)
Syntax OK
```

And still, if I try to enter `mysub.example.com` I am being redirected to `beta.example.com`. The `blog.example.com` still works perfectly fine.

Is there a chance there is a domain configuration defined somewhere else (besides the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory)?

**EDIT 3**

Additional configurations for hosts: beta.example.com and blog.example.com

beta.example.com (file: /etc/apache2/hosts-available/01-example.com )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
        ServerName beta.example.com
        ServerAlias www.beta.example.com

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-access_log" common

        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
        ServerName beta.example.com:443
        ServerAlias www.beta.example.com:443

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/beta.example.com-access_log" common

        RewriteEngine On
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        <Directory /var/www/example.com>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

blog.example.com (file: /etc/apache2/hosts-available/02-blog.example.com )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/blog.example.com"
    ServerName blog.example.com
    ServerAlias www.blog.example.com

    ErrorLog ...[path to file]
    CustomLog [path to file]

    RewriteEngine On 
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.blog.example.com$1 [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www/blog.example.com>
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The directory you should be looking in is: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: and after `a2ensite` my configuration is enabled there.

Comment: If you're being redirected to `beta.example.com`, then it probably has something to do with a rewrite/redirect rule or the default site on your server.

Comment: I checked - there's no redirection there.

Comment: try apachectl -S or apache2ctl -S

Comment: Sorry, too little feedback. At least give us the log.

Comment: What does `grep -r 'beta\.example\.com' /etc/apache2` find?

Comment: added output for `apachectl -S`

Comment: Added other debug outputs - what else do you need guys?

Comment: Try using <VirtualHost mysub.example.com:80> instead of <VirtualHost *:80>

PS: did you use NameVirtualHost directive?

Comment: Tried adding `<VirtualHost mysub.example.com:80>` - I get internal server error on all subdomains.

Comment: Where should I add `NameVirtualHost` - to `apache2.conf` or to my subdomain's specific file at `sites-available`? When I add it to `apache2.conf` I get " [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts"

Comment: Hi @Gacek, I recommend you to separate virtual hosts, using one virtual host per file, and using NameVirtualHost directive just before open the VirtualHost directive

Comment: There seems to be a weird behaviour of Apache that can be related to your experience, check Schmidt's comment at the bottom of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html. Some solutions are suggested, but those posts don't explain the cause (or are reported to work).

Comment: Added another edit

Comment: @mvillar - that is the case for me - all virtual hosts are located in separated files and there is NameVirtualHost directive

Comment: Would you post the output of `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available/` and  `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem (and solution) came out to be quite simple.

The problem was that the newly created subdomains' folders were empty - no index.php/html file in it. So the server, instead of showing it (as a dir), redirected to default domain - which was `beta.example.com`

So the configuration of vhosts was correct, and after adding some files to the folders, the subdomains strated to work.

Answer (score 2):

I advice you debug all your files, as c4f4t0r said try "apache2ctl -S" and after that try to find rewrite rules inside .htaccess files, for example:

```
find /var/www/mysub.example.com -name ".htaccess" -exec grep -l -i rewrite {} \;
```

In your main configuration file you have something "dangerous":

```
<Directory /var/www/mysub.example.com>
     AllowOverride All # <---- THIS
     Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Comment: There's nothing in `.htaccess` files, in fact these directories contain one html file right now

Answer (score 2):

You should check the file `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and look at the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` near `Listen 80`

If you don't have this line, you can't use virtualhosts based on ServerName, so it is normal that you got always the first enabled virtualhost in your browser.

Comment: Both lines are located in `ports.conf` file. And why `blog.example.com` works, but my new subdomain not?

Comment: And if you try to disable le vhost of blog.example.com ?
Can you also post the content of the vhost for blog.example.com ?

Comment: Added - se my edit

Comment: Well, the only thing for me that can explain your problem is that your mysub.example.com subdomain DNS is not well pointing on your server. There are 2 potential reasons of this :

Comment: - mysub.example.com subdomain is not configured in the right DNS server, which manager your domain example.com
  - Your server is not using a good DNS server

Comment: It is configured - checked with `nslookup`